# Fragment android:fragment Unable to instantiate fragment

Tags: android

I have problem with:

```
android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ${packageName}.${activityClass}$GeneralPreferenceFragment
```

The xml layout not working:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- These settings headers are only used on tablets. -->

<header
    android:fragment="${packageName}.${activityClass}$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_general" />
```

This works though:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- These settings headers are only used on tablets. -->

<header
    android:fragment="com.example.b.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_general" />
```

Any idea why? 
Thanks!

Example comes from SettingsActivty when creating a new project from Android Eclipse and it only breaks on a tablet size AVD.

Added this to the AndroidManifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>)
```

Comment: I had the same issue, anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not working because `${packageName}` and `${activityClass}` should be replaced with your package and activity.

You are doing it right now. Check this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example) from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there where suppose to be some magic:-) Was generated from the tools, would be good if they made a remark in the code or just fix the generation...